# Как вернуть результат SQL запроса в формате JSON?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle12c, oracle18c

Необходимо выбрать из БД несколько тысяч записей и конвертировать их в JSON для передачи в SlickGrid.

В настоящее время выбираю записи в PHP, конвертирую их из ISO в UTF-8 с помошью `iconv` и экспортирую в JSON с `json_encode`. Вся операция занимает 1 секунду на стороне БД и 5 секунд для генерации JSON (непозволительно долго).

Читал, что Oracle 12c начал поддерживать JSON, но не могу найти то, что мне действительно нужно.

Есть ли способ, вернуть результат стандартного SQL запроса в формате JSON?

Предположительно, хотел бы делать запрос, который выглядит как-то так:

```
SELECT * from table AS JSON
```

и в результате получить действительный JSON, похожий на этот:

```
[{"col1": "value1", "col2": 2}, {"col1": "valueOfRow2", "col2": 3}]
```

---

PS одно важное замечание: так как в клиенте стоит ISO-8859-2 кодировка, JSON должен быть или в UTF-8, или содержать эранированные последовательности юникода.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Return results of a sql query as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23560996) от участника [@SWilk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184839/swilk)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/23560996/6571020

Answer (score 6):

В релизе 12.2 появились новые SQL функции для генерации JSON из реляционных данных.
Для задачи как в вопросе лучше подойдут - [`JSON_OBJECT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370) и [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_ARRAYAGG.html#GUID-6D56077D-78DE-4CC0-9498-225DDC42E054).

```sql
create table tab as
    select level col1, 'value '||level col2 from dual connect by level <= 2
/ 
    
select max (rownum) rn, json_arrayagg (
    json_object (
        key 'col1' value col1,
        key 'col2' value col2
    ) format json returning clob 
) as json_doc
from tab;
```

Вернёт:

```sql
        RN JSON_DOC                                                                        
---------- ---------------------------------------------------------
         2 [{"col1":1,"col2":"value 1"},{"col1":2,"col2":"value 2"}]
```

Для более объёмных данных:

```sql
select rn, length (json_doc) json_size, json_doc from (
    <здесь запрос приведённый выше>
    cross join (select dummy from dual connect by level <= 1e5) 
    );

        RN  JSON_SIZE JSON_DOC                                                                        
---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------
    200000    5600001 [{"col1":1,"col2":"value 1"},{"col1":2,"col2":"value 2"},
```

5,6M документ за чуть более 1 сек. на слабой тестовой системе.

---

В версии 19c [синтаксис функции `JSON_OBJECT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-1084A518-A44A-4654-A796-C1DD4D8EC2AA) значительно упростился. Запрос из примера выше будет выглядеть так:

```
select json_arrayagg (  
    json_object (*) returning clob   
) as json_doc  
from tab;
```

На [Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/irib428if19k68g0v78idhlq0).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57346508) от участника [@0xdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6571020/0xdb)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Начиная с версии *Oracle 18c* можно воспользоваться [PTF (*polimorphic table function*)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-981102A8-5204-4931-B10A-93486304B184), чтобы добавить колонку с JSON представлением результата выборки из любой таблицы.
 Например:

```sql
create table tab1 as
    select level col1, 'value '||level col2, systimestamp+level created  
    from dual connect by level <= 3
/

select * from serialize.addJSON (tab1) 
where col2 like 'value%' --какое-то условие выборки
;
```

Выведет:

```
 COL1 COL2       CREATED             JSON                                                                            
----- ---------- ------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------
    1 value 1    2019-08-04 12:27:52 {"COL1":1, "COL2":"value 1", "CREATED":"2019-08-04 12:27:52"}
    2 value 2    2019-08-05 12:27:52 {"COL1":2, "COL2":"value 2", "CREATED":"2019-08-05 12:27:52"}
    3 value 3    2019-08-06 12:27:52 {"COL1":3, "COL2":"value 3", "CREATED":"2019-08-06 12:27:52"}
```

Реализация самой функции не так сложна, как это может показаться на первый взгляд:

```sql
create or replace package serialize as
    function addJSON (tab table) return table pipelined row polymorphic using serialize;
    function describe (tab in out dbms_tf.table_t) return dbms_tf.describe_t;
    procedure fetch_rows;
end serialize;
/
create or replace package body serialize as
    function describe (tab in out dbms_tf.table_t) return dbms_tf.describe_t is
    begin
        for i in 1..tab.column.count loop 
            continue when not dbms_tf.supported_type (tab.column (i).description.type);
            tab.column(i).for_read := true;
        end loop;
        return dbms_tf.describe_t (
            new_columns => dbms_tf.columns_new_t (1 => dbms_tf.column_metadata_t(name => 'JSON')));   
    end;

    procedure fetch_rows as 
        rowset dbms_tf.row_set_t;
        newcol dbms_tf.tab_varchar2_t;
        rowcnt pls_integer;
    begin
        dbms_tf.get_row_set (rowset, rowcnt);
        for rn in 1..rowcnt loop
            newcol (rn) := dbms_tf.row_to_char (rowset, rn, format=>dbms_tf.format_json); 
        end loop;
        dbms_tf.put_col (1, newcol);
    end; 
end serialize;
/
```